# Function execution is slow in callbacks. Why?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, callbacks

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
My (Heavy) Image processing functionis slow in the subscriber callback.
But if I run the same function outside ROS in release mode it is fast. (10X fast)

Why I want to put the image processing function in callback?
Because I want to process received image as soon it arrives.

Any comments!
My code looks like:

```
class storedData {
  public:    
    cv::Mat inIm = cv::Mat::zeros(376, 672, CV_8UC3);
    cv::Mat outIm = cv::Mat::zeros(376, 672, CV_8UC3);
    
    void depthCallback(const sensor_msgs::CompressedImageConstPtr& msgDepth)
    {
      try
      {
        tic2 = ros::Time::now();

        imProcess(inIm, outIm);         // Heavy Image Processing

        imPTime = ros::Time::now().toSec() - tic2.toSec();

        std::cout<<"Im process time= "<<imPTime<<std::endl;

        cv::imshow("view", outIm);
        cv::waitKey(1);
        }
      catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)
      {
            ROS_ERROR("Could not convert the depth!");
      }
    }
};
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "PredictiveDisplay");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  storedData obj;
  cv::namedWindow("view", 0);
  cv::startWindowThread();

  ros::Subscriber subDepth = nh.subscribe("/depth/depth_registered/compressed", 2, &storedData::depthCallback, &obj);
  ros::spin();

  cv::destroyWindow("view");
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319743/function-execution-is-slow-in-callbacks.-why?/) by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-03-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-03-27**:
If you could add your instrumentation to the example it would be helpful with an example of it running fast inside the callback but slow outside the callback we'd be able to help you. Without being able to reproduce it all we can do is guess at things.

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2019-03-28**:
First thing I would try would be setting ROS_BUILD_TYPE to `Release` in your CMakeLists.txt. Also clean build the package. See the linked question for options.

You can read more about it here: [http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild#Customizing_the_build_.28debug.2C_optimizations.2C_default_build_flags.29)

answers.ros.org question regarding a similar problem: [catkin-compiled-code-runs-3x-slower](https://answers.ros.org/question/71965/catkin-compiled-code-runs-3x-slower/)

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2019-03-29**:
@gvdhoorn
Thanks for your comment.

What does simple `catkin_make` do? It builds in debug or release mode?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-29**:
It's not Catkin that decides this, it's CMake.

If you don't configure any `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, CMake will use `None`, which sets no flags at all.

**Comment by [JeyP4](https://answers.ros.org/users/38257/jeyp4/) on 2019-03-29**:
Thanks @gvdhoorn.

```
catkin_make  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo
```

magically worked for me. I can accept this as an answer, if you can convert it to answer.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-03-29**:
converted to an answer. Yes, it's a little surprising, the default build has no optimizations, but actually also does not have debug info either. It's really the default that you never really want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> First thing I would try would be setting `ROS_BUILD_TYPE` to Release in your CMakeLists.txt. [..] You can read more about it here: http://wiki.ros.org/rosbuild

Please don't refer to rosbuild pages. They're only kept for archival purposes.

`ROS_BUILD_TYPE` is not used in Catkin packages. Use `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` instead.

And don't set it in your `CMakeLists.txt`, but pass it as an argument to your `catkin_make` invocation (as: `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` (or probably better: `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo`)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3